# Query about Jenkins in Windows

Tags: jenkins, openstack

I have a query where I have created two jobs in Jenkins One is to launch an openstack instance ( this use shell script) and another job is to check the image status and run validation on all those instances ( this use powershell ).

So my question here is will that be possible Jenkins to know launch instance task is completed, so now run the 2nd task where we have validation script ?

Comment: there is an option in post-build actions where you can trigger another project build

Comment: Thanks alot. I am able to see that option